# Rewriting URL from other than root folder with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to make URL rewrite to nice looking URL with .htaccess. I was trying so many ways and always get or error 500 or nothing is happening. My folder tree looks like this:

```
 root
    index.php
    .htaccess
    p
        .htaccess
        citati.php 
        ...
```

What I am trying to do is from my "p" directory when someone goes to https://example.com/p/citati/Test-test to rewrite that to https://example.com/p/citati?autor=Test-test so I can have $_GET["autor"] in my citati.php file. I have many .php files in "p" directory so that is also what I need to worry about when rewriting.
This is my .htaccess from root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.+)p/citati\/(.+)$ p/citati?autor=$1 [NC]
```

And this is what I have now in my "p" directory .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^p/citati\/(.+)$ p/citati?autor=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

It doesn't matter if I can achieve this from root .htaccess file or from "p" directory .htaccess I just want somehow to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your shown samples, please do have your root's htaccess Rule file as follows.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

For your `p` directory/folder have that htaccess Rule file as follows. You need to use same rules from root htaccess, you could inherit it.

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /p/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(citati[^.]*)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?autor=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working, but can this work without php extension, because in my p dir all my files now have .php extension again?

Comment: @Martin, Could you please do mention here for which url its working? And for which url you want it to work? That will give me better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: it is working like i wanted to, for example it works on citati/Test but my other .php files in p dir again have to have .php extension in browser console (example.com/p/o_nama.php and not example.com/p/o_nama only). I had this rule in my p folder and without it, this works fine but I need that also:  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: @Martin, ok sure, I have edited my Rules now as per your last comment, could you please check them once and let me know how it goes? Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: It is working right now, thank you very much :)